# Syncing Invalid Postgis Geometries with SymmetricDS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5, symmetricds

My SymmetricDS 3.9.2 implementation syncs databases with postgis (2.2.2) geometry on a daily basis. There is invalid postgis geometry in some of the tables. When this data with a geometry column is moved, SymmetricDS gets an error while trying to convert the geometry data from EWKT back into geometry.

For example: `failed: ERROR: geometry requires more points
  Hint: "...G(268676.801767248 5977299.18090558)" <-- parse error at position 56 within geometry`

Is there a way to sync the geometry without writing it to well known text and then converting it back into geometry?

-- this will fail because there is not enough data for a line, however, I don't want it to ever encounter this issue, I just want it to move the invalid geometry.

`SELECT ST_GeomFromText('SRID=3401;LINESTRING(152735.018168789 6064398.3443075)');`

Below is a geometry. Could we sync it like this so we do not care if it is invalid?
`"01060000A0490D00000100000001030000800100000006000000763A90954362EC40C458D64A116056410000000000000000212DA53A9462EC40BB0CB3CF07605641000000000000000073EC95C3F267EC40DCAA4ADDE05F56410000000000000000BF4F7D4B3F74EC407A48E55CE45F56410000000000000000D409C190AF73EC40F052FA69116056410000000000000000763A90954362EC40C458D64A116056410000000000000000"`